# problems with multiple levels of inheritance in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using a typescript library of classes for api access, which has been automatically generated by a toolset that defines  a class ("**UserApi**") having specific methods extending a "base" class ("**BaseApi**") that has generic methods. There is also a model interface  "**User**";

These classes are using generics to ensure / keep type safety.

I have now a need to create a third class (one of my own, not part of the library) that itself extends "**UserApi**" .

The first problem I ran into is that I was wanting to override the `find" method (defined in "**BaseApi**")

so, in my class "**MyClass**" I have

```
import {User} from 'sdk';

export class UserStoreService extends UserApi {
    constructor(
    ) {
        super();
    }

    public find(): Observable<User[]> {
        return super.find();
    }
}
```

the definition of the `find` method in the "**BaseApi**" class is

```
public find<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.request(
```

I get a syntax error

```
Property 'find' in type 'UserStoreService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'UserApi'.   Type '() => Observable<User[]>' is not assignable to type '<T>() => Observable<T[]>'.
    Type 'Observable<User[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T[]>'.
      Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
        Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

so I thought I'd change the `super.find()` to be `super.find<User>()` but got the same error

how can I make these function calls match ?

The second question is about the levels of class extending going on here. The thought has struck me that if I can modify the templates used by the library, I could actually just generate *all* of the code into a single, model-specific class, not 3.

I see several advantages

- less files to deal with
- less generics to deal with
- *much* easier code to read and maintain

What is the downside to this ?

- increase in package size (the base class is 29k (!)) - so each model file would be increased by this amount

Comment: This line is bad: public find(): Observable<User[]> {
        return super.find(filter, customHeaders);
    } from where do you get "filter" and "customHeaders"? It should probably look more like this: public find(filter: string, customHeaders: Object): Observable<User[]> {
        return super.find(filter, customHeaders);
    }

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I tried to simplify and forgot to remove those from the post.  If both the function and the super have no parameters, the error is still the same

Answer (score 1):

One easy way out might be to just remove the override of `find` in `UserStoreService`.  But the real problem is that the declaration of `find` in `BaseApi` is probably not what you intend.  It means that every `BaseApi` instance (including subclass instances) must support `find` for every type `T`.  You probably want to make `T` a type parameter of `BaseApi` (i.e., `BaseApi<T>`) and remove the `<T>` from the `find` method so that each subclass can specify the single type `T` that it supports.  For example, `UserApi` would extend `BaseApi<User>`.

Comment: that is exactly what I was thinking - was very confused about why the methods wold be defined like that in the baseApi. I'll reach out to the original developer and ask him directly. It may solve several issues ;)

Thanks!