# Pass generic type as type parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics, types

I am struggling to come up with a solution to a problem i'm facing, where i am trying to use a generic type as a type parameter.
I have the following two classes/types:

UserModel.ts:

```
export class UserModel{

  private _id : string;
  public get id() : string {
      return this._id;
  }
  public set id(v : string) {
      this._id = v;
  }

  ....
}
```

HttpResponse.ts:

```
export class HttpResponse<T>{

  private _success : boolean;
  public get success() : boolean {
      return this._success;
  }
  public set success(v : boolean) {
      this._success = v;
  }

  private _model : T;
  public get model() : T {
      return this._model;
  }
  public set model(v : T) {
      this._model = v;
  }
}
```

As you can guess, I am using this to have a generic type to handle http calls easily. The intended use is to call my http method with the HttpResponse type **and** whatever the expect result type is as the type parameter. For example, when making a user related http call the type parameter would be `HttpResponse<UserModel>>` or for a resource related call it would be `HttpResponse<ResourceModel>>`. However, i don't seem to be having any luck when trying this.

In my data service I have a method that POSTS to the server called 'create' and

```
create<T>(data: any){
  //Angular's HttpClient
  return this.http.post<T>(data, ...);
}
```

I then have a service that extends this class and overloads the create method with some extra bits before it calls super.create. I run into the issue at this point because I want to pass in `HttpResponse<Type the service should return>` which in the following case would be `HttpResponse<UserModel>`:

```
create<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(user: UserModel){
  //stuff happens here
  return super.create<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(user, ...);
}
```

However, this returns a syntax error at `create<HttpResponse<UserModel>>`.
I had a look online and found another way to achieve this as something along the lines of:

```
create<HttpResponse, UserModel>(user: any){
  //stuff happens here
  return super.create<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(user, ...);
}
```

But, again, this returns an error stating "HttpResponse is not generic".

The design idea is that by passing in the types in this manner, the json response from the server can be automatically mapped into the appropriate type, making it simple to use the response throughout the application

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong in my design?

Comment: Who is `super.create`? Do you plan to have classes derived from `HttpResponse` or is it just the one and you just want to pass in the type of the result? Do you want to instantiate instances of the result type or will you just return the json value as the result? Could you please elaborate a bit on your use case.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Apologies, i was trying to keep it simple to avoid confusion, but i shall update the post. However, the main purpose is as you said and to just have one HttpResponse class that accepts whatever type of result we expect. e.g. `HttpResponse<BookingModle>` or `HttpResponse<UserModel>` etc.

Comment: Simple is good, but it also has to be clear what you are trying to achieve, it's a delicate balance  :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Very true, let me know if the edit adds some clarity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subclass has to maintain the entire interface of its base class (with some exceptions that aren't relevant here).  If your data service base class contains a `create` method that is generic and works for *every* `T`, then your subclass cannot override `create` with a method that only works for `T = HttpResponse<UserModel>`.  Instead, consider (1) defining a new method with a different name or (2) moving the `T` parameter from the `create` method to the base class itself, so that when your subclass extends the base class, it can specify the single `T` that it works with.  (Compare to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52457391).)  If this doesn't seem to be what you're looking for, then please provide more information.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I knew I was doing something stupid. Marked my dataService with <T> and then in the dataService create method i return:
  `return this.http.post<HttpResponse<T>>(data, ...);`

Which seems to make much more sense!